# Error in month.abb[ ]: only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

Tags: r, data.table, data-wrangling

I want to convert numbers into months; for numbers larger than 12, add "2nd year" before month. The data is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joyce-john/mastering-product-analytics/main/registrations.csv):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

rg <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joyce-john/mastering-product-analytics/main/registrations.csv") 

rg[,.(month_rg2 = fifelse(registration_month<= 12, 
                          month.abb[registration_month], 
                          paste0("2nd Year ", month.abb[registration_month-12])))]
```

> Error in month.abb[registration_month - 12] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

I know that number `12` is taken as `no` by `fifelse` and `month.abb[]` doesn't identify zero. is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 4):

**1)** fifelse will evaluate both legs at all values of registration_month. Avoid using fifelse or ifelse if you don't want both legs evaluated or ensure that the subscript within month.abb is valid for all values of registration_month.

It can be done this way which only uses ifelse to set the "2nd Year" string.

```
# convert vector of month numbers to formatted strings
abb <- function(x) {
  paste0(ifelse(x > 12, "2nd Year ", ""), rep(month.abb, 2)[x])
}
rg[, .(month_rg2 = abb(registration_month))]
```

**2)** Alternately in each leg of the fifelse replace `month.abb` with `rep(month.abb, 2)` so that the subscript never overflows.

```
rg[,.(month_rg2 = fifelse(registration_month <= 12, 
       rep(month.abb, 2)[registration_month], 
       paste0("2nd Year ", rep(month.abb, 2)[registration_month])))]
```

**3)** or in each leg replace `registration_month` with `(registration_month - 1) %% 12 + 1` to map all values to the 1-12 range.

```
rg[,.(month_rg2 = fifelse(registration_month<= 12, 
      month.abb[(registration_month - 1) %% 12 + 1], 
      paste0("2nd Year ", month.abb[(registration_month - 1) %% 12 + 1])))]
```

### Note

To avoid this answer being not reproducible due to potential loss of the external link in the question this subset of the data was used.

```
library(data.table)

rg <- structure(list(registration_month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21), id = c("id_10033", 
"id_10048", "id_10052", "id_10044", "id_10006", "id_10000", "id_10053", 
"id_10008", "id_10016", "id_10002", "id_10", "id_10025", "id_1001", 
"id_1", "id_1000", "id_10009", "id_10005", "id_1002", "id_10051", 
"id_1004", "id_10004"), region = c("EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", "EMEA", 
"ROW", "ROW", "ROW", "ROW", "ROW", "EMEA", "ROW", "ROW", "ROW", 
"America", "ROW", "ROW", "ROW", "ROW", "ROW", "ROW", "EMEA"), 
    operating_system = c("Windows", "Windows", "Windows", "Mac", 
    "Unknown", "Windows", "Windows", "Windows", "Unknown", "Linux", 
    "Mac", "Unknown", "Mac", "Windows", "Windows", "Windows", 
    "Mac", "Windows", "Windows", "Windows", "Mac")), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), class = "data.frame")
rg <- as.data.table(rg)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you can try this -

```
library(data.table)

rg[, month_rg2 := month.abb[fifelse(registration_month<= 12, 
                             registration_month, registration_month - 12)]]

rg[registration_month > 12 , month_rg2 := paste('2nd year', month_rg2)]
rg

              id registration_month  region operating_system    month_rg2
#    1: id_10033                  1    EMEA          Windows          Jan
#    2: id_10050                  1     ROW          Unknown          Jan
#    3: id_10054                  1    EMEA          Windows          Jan
#    4: id_10080                  1     ROW          Unknown          Jan
#    5: id_10098                  1     ROW          Windows          Jan
#   ---                                                                  
#40122:  id_9868                 21    EMEA              Mac 2nd year Sep
#40123:  id_9885                 21     ROW          Unknown 2nd year Sep
#40124:  id_9888                 21     ROW          Windows 2nd year Sep
#40125:  id_9905                 21     ROW          Unknown 2nd year Sep
#40126:  id_9919                 21 America          Windows 2nd year Sep
```

`fifelse` `registration_month > 12` subtract 12 from it and get the corresponding month name. Also `paste` `'2nd year'` to those month names.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `fifelse` to give prefix `""` or `2nd Year`, and use `%%` over the values in `registration_month` to ensure the month numbers is constrained within `1` to `12`, e.g.,

```
rg[
  ,
  month_rg2 :=
    paste0(
      fifelse(
        registration_month <= 12,
        "",
        "2nd Year "
      ),
      month.abb[(registration_month - 1) %% 12 + 1]
    )
][]
```

and you will see

```
            id registration_month  region operating_system    month_rg2
    1: id_10033                  1    EMEA          Windows          Jan
    2: id_10050                  1     ROW          Unknown          Jan
    3: id_10054                  1    EMEA          Windows          Jan
    4: id_10080                  1     ROW          Unknown          Jan
    5: id_10098                  1     ROW          Windows          Jan
   ---
40122:  id_9868                 21    EMEA              Mac 2nd Year Sep
40123:  id_9885                 21     ROW          Unknown 2nd Year Sep
40124:  id_9888                 21     ROW          Windows 2nd Year Sep
40125:  id_9905                 21     ROW          Unknown 2nd Year Sep
40126:  id_9919                 21 America          Windows 2nd Year Sep
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sapply`:

```
rg[,.(month_rg2 = sapply(registration_month,
                         function(month) ifelse(month<= 12,
                                                month.abb[month], 
                                                paste0("2nd Year ", month.abb[month-12]))))]

          month_rg2
    1:          Jan
    2:          Jan
    3:          Jan
    4:          Jan
    5:          Jan
   ---             
40122: 2nd Year Sep
40123: 2nd Year Sep
40124: 2nd Year Sep
40125: 2nd Year Sep
40126: 2nd Year Sep
```